# Xcode - does not match any targeted device families - iPhone 6 plus "M239"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

App works fine on all devices but this one. Xcode prompts:
The run destination [phone name] - M239 is not valid for Running the scheme 'TST'.
[phone name] iPhone 6 Plus - M239 doesn’t match any of [appname].app’s targeted device families. You can expand [appname].app’s targeted device families to support [phone name] iPhone 6 Plus - M239.
- I tried a lot of stuff. Lots of articles about setting architecture. E.g. set to "armv7 armv7s arm64" works fine in another project; but doesn't work 
here.

This project is several years old. It still has Provisioning Profile (deprecated) in the settings; but I tried to set that properly too.

Is this phone hacked or something perhaps? Or what else can I try?

Comment: Did not resolve and used another device instead.